# Custom arrayadapter that is of type custom model is returning only one value

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

I have the following custom array adapter of my custom model -

```java
public class ColorAttributeArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductAttributeModel> {

    private List<ProductAttributeModel> titles;
    private Context context;
    private MarketApiCalls marketApiCalls;

    public ColorAttributeArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<ProductAttributeModel> titles) {
        super(context, R.layout.product_attribute_spinner_row_item, R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_textview, titles);
        this.titles = titles;
        this.context = context;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_PORTAL_PRODUCTION_URL)
//                .baseUrl(BASE_PORTAL_STAGE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        marketApiCalls = retrofit.create(MarketApiCalls.class);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_attribute_spinner_row_item, parent, false);
        }
//        String currentString = titles.get(position).getAttributeValues().get(position);
        List<String> attributeValues = titles.get(position).getAttributeValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributeValues.size(); i++) {
            String currentString = attributeValues.get(i);

            //Setting the image color
            ImageView imageView = listItem.findViewById(R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_image_view);
            Map<String, String> htmlStandardColorMap = ColorUtil.getHtmlStandardColorMap();
            if (htmlStandardColorMap.containsKey(currentString)) {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(htmlStandardColorMap.get(currentString)));
            } else {
                String colorURL = COLORS_API.concat(Uri.encode(currentString, "UTF-8"));
                Picasso.get().load(colorURL).resize(90,90).into(imageView);
            }

            TextView value = listItem.findViewById(R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_textview);
            value.setText(currentString);

        }
        return listItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

```java
public class ProductAttributeModel {

    private String attributeName;

    private List<String> attributeValues;

    public ProductAttributeModel(String attributeName, List<String> attributeValues) {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
        this.attributeValues = attributeValues;
    }

    public String getAttributeName() {
        return attributeName;
    }

    public void setAttributeName(String attributeName) {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }

    public List<String> getAttributeValues() {
        return attributeValues;
    }

    public void setAttributeValues(List<String> attributeValues) {
        this.attributeValues = attributeValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductAttributeModel{" +
                "attributeName='" + attributeName + '\'' +
                ", attributeValues=" + attributeValues +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and I am starting my adapter from  the following function -

```java
 @Override
    public void setProductPurchaseAttributes() {
        selectedProductAttributesMap = selectedProduct.getAttributesList();
        /*Starting index is the index in which we start to add the dynamic linear layouts that represents products attributes.
        This number should be incremented by 1 every time we do any changes to `activity_product_page.xml` file otherwise the dynamic views
        will be created in the wrong place.
         */
        int startingIndex = 7;
        if (!isProductAvailable) return;
        ArrayList<ProductAttributeModel> productAttributeModels = new ArrayList<>();
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : selectedProductAttributesMap.entrySet()) {

            //Key and value for each iteration

            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> value = entry.getValue();

            //creating the linear layout

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            //creating the layout params

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams attributeLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //setting margins
            /*These margins values are different than the values in the XML of the activity because this is a dynamically created view*/
            attributeLayoutParams.setMargins(48, 30, 48, 0);
            textParams.setMargins(0, 60, 0, 0);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(attributeLayoutParams);

            //creating the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);

            textView.setText(key.concat(":"));
            textView.setLayoutParams(textParams);

            //creating the spinner
            spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);


            //attribute list adapter
            productAttributeModels.add(new ProductAttributeModel(key, value));
            ColorAttributeArrayAdapter adapter = new ColorAttributeArrayAdapter(this, productAttributeModels);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            //adding to the linear layout

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            linearLayout.addView(spinner);

            //adding linear layout to root view

            productDetailsViewGroup.addView(linearLayout, startingIndex);
            startingIndex++;
        }
    }
```

for some reason, I get only one result instead of multiple results.

Moving the adapter instantiation to the end of the for loop won't help, tried that already.

When doing debugging, I saw that the object of the adapter holds 4 items inside the list but I am showing only the last one. Seems like I am writing the object and not adding it. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Move these lines outside your for loop completely

```
   ColorAttributeArrayAdapter adapter = new ColorAttributeArrayAdapter(this, productAttributeModels);
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You are currently creating a new adapter in each run of the for loop with the latest attribute model and attaching it to the spinner, thus the spinner only has the last adapter with the last attribute model when it reaches the end. Your adapter created outside the for loop will have all the attributes you added to the `productAttributeModels` list.